# Excel/VBA Comparing two columns and copying the cell contents from a third column into a fourth column in two different sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have to write a macro in Excel for a co-worker. It should import .xlsx files and then compare first and last names between two columns in two different sheets. If a match has been found in the second sheet, the cell contents of another column in the second sheet have to be copied and pasted into a column in the first sheet. The macro to import the files is done and works perfectly. Due to me being very new to Macros/VBA, I'm experiencing some difficulties in comparing between the sheets and copying.

Example:

**Sheet 1**

***Column A*** (First and Last Name)

- John Doe
- Luigi Ditalia
- Mario Ditalia

*Column N* (DEPARTEMENTS)

**Sheet 2**

***Column B*** (DEPARTEMENTS)

- Finances
- Administration
- Helpdesk

***Column C*** (First and Last Name)

- John Doe
- Luigi Ditalia
- Mario Ditalia

As you can see, the user "*John Doe*" is present in Column A in sheet 1 AND in Column C in sheet 2. Now I need to copy the cell contents of Column B (for the same person) to the Column N in the same row as "John Doe". How can I do this?

This is what I have so far:

```
Sub compareCols()
    Dim masterWorkbook As Workbook
    Set masterWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook

    Dim masterSheet_caption As String
    Dim masterSheet_msg As String
    Dim masterSheet_Name As String
    masterSheet_caption = "Choosing a mastersheet"
    masterSheet_msg = "In which sheet should the departement of the users be written in if a match has been found in the imported sheet? (this will be the mastersheet)"
    masterSheet_Name = InputBox(masterSheet_msg, masterSheet_caption, User)

    Dim masterSheet_columnFL_msg As String
    Dim masterSheet_columnFL_FirstCell As String
    masterSheet_columnFL_msg = "Which is the first cell (in the mastersheet) in which the first and the last names of the users can be found?"
    masterSheet_columnFL_FirstCell = InputBox(masterSheet_columnFL_msg, masterSheet_caption, User)

    Dim importedSheet_caption As String
    Dim importedSheet_msg As String
    Dim importedSheet_Name As String
    importedSheet_caption = "Choosing the imported sheet"
    importedSheet_msg = "What sheet has been imported to check for duplicates in the columns containing first and last names? (default: import)"
    importedSheet_Name = InputBox(importedSheet_msg, importedSheet_caption, User)

    Dim masterSheet As Worksheet
    Dim importedSheet As Worksheet
    Set masterSheet = masterWorkbook.Worksheets(masterSheet_Name)
    Set importedSheet = masterWorkbook.Worksheets(importedSheet_Name)

End Sub
```

**FOLLOWUP**

At least VBA is English only. Therefore I'm going to try that. This should do the trick:

```
Sub test()
Dim masterWorkbook As Workbook
Set masterWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook

Dim masterSheet As Worksheet
Dim importedSheet As Worksheet
Set masterSheet = masterWorkbook.Worksheets("Online")
Set importedSheet = masterWorkbook.Worksheets("import")

masterSheet.Range("N1:N871").Formula = _
"=INDIRECT(""importedSheet!B"" & INDEX(MATCH(A1,importedSheet!C:C,0),0,0))"

masterSheet.Range("N1:N871").Value = masterSheet.Range("N1:N871").Value
End Sub
```

All I get with this is 0s in the column N in sheet 1 (masterSheet). But at least it is something! Now I'll just need to find the "error". And I guess it's the traduction. Give me 5 minutes.

Comment: You want the departments to be filled in Sheet1 for relevant names? If yes then you can use a formula to achieve what you want

Comment: Yes, the departements in sheet 1 shall be filled with the departements in sheet 2 according to the First and Last names. Sadly, it has to be a macro because my coworkers want to have it that way and they want to use it in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NON VBA SOLUTION**

A Simple formula like

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet2!B" & INDEX(MATCH(A1,Sheet2!C:C,0),0,0))
```

Can solve your problem

[image]

**VBA SOLUTION**

I have hardcoded the cell address to show an example. Please amend as applicable.

```
Sheet1.Range("N1:N3").Formula = _
"=INDIRECT(""Sheet2!B"" & INDEX(MATCH(A1,Sheet2!C:C,0),0,0))"

Sheet1.Range("N1:N3").Value = Sheet1.Range("N1:N3").Value
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm going to try it now.

Comment: This is the result I have: http://i.imgur.com/ychPwmN.png. I renamed "Sheet2" to "import" as this is the name of the sheet. I'm afraid it doesn't work like this. Excel doesn't seem to recognize is as function?!

Comment: Yours is not an English version so you may have different name for the functions?

Comment: ++ very good @SiddharthRout. midn8 are you sure you don't use `;` instead of `,` in the formulas?

Comment: Yes. Do you see any errors there? I wrote it a bit different because in sheet 2; column C is now column B and column B is now column A: masterSheet.Range("N2:N346").Formula = _
"=INDIREKT(""import!A"" & INDEX(VERGLEICH(A1,import!B:B,0),0,0))"

masterSheet.Range("N2:N346").Value = masterSheet.Range("N2:N346").Value

Comment: Awesome Siddarth! only issue is if no name match, then value not available error for the cell.  Any quick way to error check to avoid that error?

Answer (score 0):

At least VBA is English only. Therefore I'm going to try that. This should do the trick:

```
Sub test()
Dim masterWorkbook As Workbook
Set masterWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook

Dim masterSheet As Worksheet
Dim importedSheet As Worksheet
Set masterSheet = masterWorkbook.Worksheets("Online")
Set importedSheet = masterWorkbook.Worksheets("import")

masterSheet.Range("N1:N871").Formula = _
"=INDIRECT(""importedSheet!B"" & INDEX(MATCH(A1,importedSheet!C:C,0),0,0))"

masterSheet.Range("N1:N871").Value = masterSheet.Range("N1:N871").Value
End Sub
```

All I get with this is 0s in the column N in sheet 1 (masterSheet). But at least it is something! Now I'll just need to find the "error". And I guess it's the traduction. Give me 5 minutes.

Comment: Is your sheet "importedSheet" or "import"?

Comment: My sheet is named import but in VBA im using variables, see: Set importedSheet = masterWorkbook.Worksheets("import")

Comment: Then Change `"=INDIRECT(""importedSheet!B"" & INDEX(MATCH(A1,importedSheet!C:C,0),0,0))"` to `"=INDIRECT(""import!B"" & INDEX(MATCH(A1,import!C:C,0),0,0))"`

Comment: I have moved your code to your question. Please delete this post as it is not an answer to your question :)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'll try it as soon as I can. I just know that it will get trickier as the cells dont match exactly. Ex: John Doe, DOE John, John Doé ...

Comment: Tried it. Results: http://i.imgur.com/oDsiE0b.png http://i.imgur.com/7elDIyU.png Correct traduction. Not working. I may not give up :/